# When does a floating point number overflow?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

Why is

```
Number.MAX_VALUE + Number.MAX_VALUE == Number.MAX_VALUE
=> false
```

but

```
Number.MAX_VALUE + Number.MIN_VALUE == Number.MAX_VALUE
=> true
```

?

My expectation was, that everything I add to the maximum value must overflow.

Comment: The number overflows when the mantissa and exponent are as "big" as possible. Adding `MIN_VALUE` doesn't do that because it's vanishingly small in comparison to `MAX_VALUE`. Think of it as all the non-zero digits being far, far to the right, and therefore they have no net effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript’s `Number.MAX_VALUE` is misnamed. It is not the maximum representable value. It is the maximum representable finite value. The actual maximum representable value is infinity.

If the name were correct, so that `Number.MAX_VALUE` were infinity, then `Number.MAX_VALUE + Number.MAX_VALUE == Number.MAX_VALUE` would be true, because infinity plus infinity is true.

As it is the mathematical value of `Number.MAX_VALUE + Number.MAX_VALUE` is beyond the representable finite values, so it is rounded to infinity.

`Number.MAX_VALUE + Number.MIN_VALUE == Number.MAX_VALUE` is true because arithmetic rounds to the nearest representable value, and adding a small value to the maximum finite value produces a result very close to the maximum finite value, so it rounds to the maximum finite value.

(Note: The rule about rounding to the nearest representable value treats infinity as if it were in a normal place at the end of the finite values, so any result that is greater than or equal to `Number.MAX_VALUE` plus half a “step” beyond it rounds to infinity.)

Answer (score 2):

Imagine it like this:

MAX_VALUE = Infinite

MIN_VALUE = 0

So, when you add MAX_VALUE with MIN_VALUE it's like you added 0. So it's still MAX_VALUE.

> Think of it as all the non-zero digits being far, far to the right, and therefore they have no net effect.